# Using jQuery to select table group columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is a part of my table columns I want to select. Here's the code:

```
<tr>    
<th colspan="2">
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

Now i want to be able to select the whole big column. Tried many methods but none work so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which column?  and please show us what you tried.

Comment: What is colspan doing in <th>?

Comment: All the code above is actually a single column of my big table. I want to be able to select this column and hide it. So far I've tried to use some online plugins and researched on google but no luck so far.

Comment: is it me or the `th` should be in a `tr` ?

Comment: @Narendra: why would a th couldn't have colspan?

Comment: @patuluc yes the th should be in the tr, fixed it. But problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

well it will be

```
$('th[colspan="2"],td[colspan="2"]')
```

Comment: If say it's in the third column of my table. I should use $('th:nth-child(3)[colspan="2"], td:nth-child(3)[colspan="2"]').hide(); to select as you suggested?

Comment: no, you said you need the big columns so this $('th[colspan="2"],td[colspan="2"]') will select what any cell that has col span of 2 , no matter if it is the second or third or any location

Comment: just tried it. Won't work. You have selected and hided the first and the last row part, but not selecting the mid row, specifically the second cell of the second row is not selected.

Comment: well in the second row you are not having any big cell , you have two small cells <tr> <td></td><td></td></tr>

Comment: Yes. That's intended and how my table is structured. So is there a way to select the whole column as I want to use jQuery to hide it.

Comment: you are open to change html a little ?

Answer (score 0):

well if you know which column it is , ie 3rd column then it will be like

```
$("table td:nth-child(3),table th:nth-child(3)")
```

another answer could be

in case you can change the markup

```
<tr>    
<th colspan="2" class="bigcol">
</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="bigcol"></td><td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="bigcol"></td>
</tr>


$(".bigcol").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

This bit more complex jquery code does the trick. It is looking for a `th` and all the `td` with a specific colspan (so it's not perfect, because you can't have 2 big `td`s ina a row). It also hides the required amount of `td`s with 1 colspan. http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/xz6W4/

```
var colw = 2;
var position = $("th[colspan=" + colw + "]").prevAll().length;
$("th[colspan=" + colw + "]").hide();
$("tr").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("th").length !== 0) {    
        return;
    }    
    if ($(this).find("td[colspan=" + colw + "]").length !== 0) {
        $(this).find("td[colspan=" + colw + "]").hide();        
        return;
    } 
    for (var i = 1; i <= colw; i++) {
        $(this).find("td:nth-child(" + (position + i) + ")").hide();
    }
});
```